# CakePHP inplace editing in db with validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on my first cakephp app. Auth and the original validation is working perfectly.

I made a little modification on the user's private page, where personal datas shown, i made it to be able to edit data in place with jQuery+jEditable, working perfectly.

My problem is, when im modifying for example email to a bad one, i mean "someone@.com" or "somone.com@asdf.com". So I think you can get that my app cant use the "validation" when im modifying data with in-place way.

I would make the validation for all fields: not empty, correct e-mail syntax and the new password with md5 hash generating and password confirmation somehow.

You will see everything is working, but the password is not, i dont have any idea how to do it with confirmation field and md5 hash generating.

It would be grateful if you can help me a little, im newbie.

I also would know about this security, what i have to take attention for?

Here are the codes:

UsersController.php

```
    public function in_place_editing($id = null) {

    if (!$id) return;

    if ($this->request->data) {

    # get all the fields with its values (there should be only one, but anyway ...)
    foreach($this->data['User'] as $field => $value)
    {
      # check if the provided field name is acceptable
      switch($field)
      {
        case 'email':
        case 'postcode':
        case 'city':
        case 'address':
        case 'phone':
          break;
        default:
          $this->set('updated_value', '');
        return;
      }

      $this->User->id = $id;
      $this->User->save($field, $value);
      $this->set('updated_value', $value);
      $this->beforeRender();
      $this->layout = 'ajax';


    }
  }

}
```

index.ctp (this is the private datas page)

```
<h2>Personal details</h2>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $userdata[0]['User']['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>E-mail</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->inPlaceEditing->input('User', 'email', $userdata[0]['User']['id'],
            array('value' => $userdata[0]['User']['email'],
            'actionName' => 'users/in_place_editing',
            'type' => 'text',
            'cancelText' => 'Cancel',
            'submitText' => 'Save',
            'toolTip' => 'Click to edit',
            //'containerType' => 'td'
            )
            );
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Postcode</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->inPlaceEditing->input('User', 'postcode', $userdata[0]['User']['id'],
            array('value' => $userdata[0]['User']['postcode'],
            'actionName' => 'users/in_place_editing',
            'type' => 'text',
            'cancelText' => 'Cancel',
            'submitText' => 'Save',
            'toolTip' => 'Click to edit',
            //'containerType' => 'td'
            )
            );
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->inPlaceEditing->input('User', 'city', $userdata[0]['User']['id'],
            array('value' => $userdata[0]['User']['city'],
            'actionName' => 'users/in_place_editing',
            'type' => 'text',
            'cancelText' => 'Cancel',
            'submitText' => 'Save',
            'toolTip' => 'Click to edit',
            //'containerType' => 'td'
            )
            );
            ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->inPlaceEditing->input('User', 'address', $userdata[0]['User']['id'],
            array('value' => $userdata[0]['User']['address'],
            'actionName' => 'users/in_place_editing',
            'type' => 'text',
            'cancelText' => 'Cancel',
            'submitText' => 'Save',
            'toolTip' => 'Click to edit',
            //'containerType' => 'td'
            )
            );
            ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Phone number</td>
            <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->inPlaceEditing->input('User', 'phone', $userdata[0]['User']['id'],
            array('value' => $userdata[0]['User']['phone'],
            'actionName' => 'users/in_place_editing',
            'type' => 'text',
            'cancelText' => 'Cancel',
            'submitText' => 'Save',
            'toolTip' => 'Click to edit',
            //'containerType' => 'td'
            )
            );
            ?>
            </td>

    </tr>
    </table><br>
<h2>User and password</h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><?php echo $userdata[0]['User']['username']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <td>Password</th>
            <td>Modify</td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: sorry in the UsersController.php the line: "$this->User->save($field, $value);" is "$this->User->saveField($field, $value);"

just a little correction for the clear sight

Answer (score 0):

Add validation rules to model that you have created for user. its example for email validation for your user model. You can use more validation for phone,postcode as numeric value

```
var $validate =array('email'=>array(
                                 'Email'    =>  array(
                               'rule'=>'email',
                              'message'=>'Improper email address'
                                )));
```

check out link : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::email

Comment: thanks for the reply,
my User.php validation is working fine, when im putting data from input fields, but my problem is, validation doesn't want to work if im editing in place with jquery :S i did everything like you wrote

Comment: it is working like if jquery doesn't take attention to my validations in User.php model

Answer (score 0):

```
    OR you can directly add validation rule to controller.

    $this->User->set($this->request->data);
  <pre>  
    $this->User->validate['email'] = array('Mail'=>array( 'rule' => 'email',
                              'message' => 'improperemail','on'=>create')));
</pre>

before saveField check for validation.
as if($this->Users->validates())
{
enter saveField code
}
```

Comment: could you please put it to my code as you wish its working? i cant get it work :SS

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach($this->data['User'] as $field => $value)
            {
              # check if the provided field name is acceptable
              switch($field)
              {
                case 'email':
                case 'postcode':
                case 'city':
                case 'address':
                case 'phone':
                  break;
                default:
                  $this->set('updated_value', '');
                return;
              }

        $this->User->set($this->request->data);

            $this->User->validate['email'] = array('Mail'=>array( 'rule' => 'email',
                                      'message' => 'improperemail','on'=>'update')));

        if($this->Users->validates())
        {
              $this->User->id = $id;
              $this->User->save($field, $value);
        }
    else
    {
           $this->Session->setFlash('not a valid field your are posting');
            $errors=$this->User->validationerrors;
    }
```